# Regex: Replace Characters In-between Two Characters

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm having trouble using Regex to replace strings that have a `?` in between two characters. Two examples of what I'd like Regex to match are:

```
• Replace thi?s question mark but not this one?
• ? Replace the lonely question mark
```

What's the best way to:

a) Match a character surrounded by other characters

b) Match a character that is on it's own and has no characters before it or after it

I'm using PHP preg_match and MySQL REGEXP to preform these pattern matchings. For MySQL I've tried:

```
SELECT description
FROM locations
WHERE description
REGEXP '/|([^?]+)\/'
```

For PHP I've tried:

```
preg_match('/|([^?]+)\/', $string);
```

Comment: So what problem did you run into?

Comment: Ah! Nice avatar.  What's in there?

Comment: @devnull Every pattern I try doesn't yield the results I'm looking for.

Comment: @Enijar Could you mention a couple of those that you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this one for PHP:

```
(?<!\w(?=\? ))\?(?!\s*$)\s*
```

`(?!\s*$)` is a negative lookahead that will prevent a `?` from matching if it is at the end of a sentence (I added whitespaces just in case).

`(?<!\w(?=\? ))` is a little more complex. It will prevent a match if the `?` is preceded by a `\w` character (typically read as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and followed by a space.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fE1iT7)

I don't know whether mysql supports lookbehinds though.

---

```
|([^?]+)\
```

This is your current regex and I don't think your PHP code runs. The `\` at the end is not escaping anything (in fact, it's trying to escape the delimiter) so... :s

Comment: Thanks for this improvement.

Comment: @Enijar You're welcome! By the way, I don't think that the other answer is correct, because... [it is matching practically everything](http://regex101.com/r/aX7eD9), but that's only me. If it really works for you, apologies for not understanding your requirement.

Comment: You're correct. The other answer is only half correct for my question. I've updated my answer choice. Thank you again.

Comment: @Enijar Glad to have helped then :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo Code Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/63QO8n)**</kbd>

#### Pattern

```
/(\w+)?(\w+)/g
```

[**Test**](http://www.regexr.com/38lo8) this Pattern

---

#### PHP

```
<?php
    echo preg_replace("/(\w+)?(\w+)/i", "thi?s", "?");
?>
```

#### Result

```
?
```

Hope this help you!